# vscode with django-template installed does not auto indent

Tags: html, django, visual-studio-code

I am using vscode to edit django template files. After installing django or django-template extensions the auto indent does not work anymore.

before [image: e]

after [image]

Already tried:

```
"files.associations": {
        "**/*.html": "html",
        "**/templates/*/*.html": "django-html"
    },
"emmet.includeLanguages": {"django-html": "html"},
```